# Simple question about the electromagnetic tensor written as a 2-form

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus

I noticed that the 2 form (Electromagnetic tensor) is written as:

$$F= F^{ab}e^a \wedge e^b$$ while we know that $$F= F_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu \wedge dx^\nu$$

Is there something wrong with the indices placement in the first written equation (please note that the e's are 1 forms)

Comment: Where have you seen it written in the first manner?

Comment: my friend's class notes

Comment: I suspect one of the indices were transcribed incorrectly.

Comment: I was doubting that the F {a and b } indices must be placed lower, but the notes and exercises that follow do not claim this. Am I right?

Comment: I'd have to see the notes, but if it continues with the incorrect indices, you could be correct.

Comment: No from your own knowledge is it wrong to place indices that way?

Comment: Yes, see the [Einstein notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first form is incorrect, assuming usual index conventions. It would not be coordinate-invariant, since all terms would transform the same way during coordinate change.

Summation always happens on indices with different placement, and it is customary when it comes to differential forms to use components with lower indices, (ie. the value differential forms in each point lie in exterior products of the cotangent space) because they behave nicely under maps, and can be differentiated without having to rely on a metric.

From these considerations, the second form is correct.